# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer Breaking Autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasypt

I am having an issue with Spring and the Jasypt `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. It appears that I am breaking the autowiring of the `HandlerStageInterceptor` component. When I remove the last three beans in my configuration related to the placeholder, everything works as expected and the interceptor is registered. When I leave the beans in, the normally autowired interceptor is null and a `NullPointerException` is thrown by Spring.

I'm having a hard time debugging this problem. The autowired component in question does not contain any usages of `@Value` with a property that would need to be resolved/decrypted, nor do any of it's dependencies.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.example.package"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private HandlerStageInterceptor handlerStageInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("===== Registry: " + handlerStageInterceptor);
        registry.addInterceptor(handlerStageInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public EnvironmentStringPBEConfig setupEnvironmentStringPBEConfig() {
        EnvironmentStringPBEConfig config = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();

        config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        config.setPasswordEnvName("APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD");

        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public StandardPBEStringEncryptor setupStringEncryptor() {
        StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();

        encryptor.setConfig(setupEnvironmentStringPBEConfig());

        return encryptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer setupPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(setupStringEncryptor());

        configurer.setLocation(new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource("classpath:properties/application.${RUN_ENV}.properties"));
        configurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);

        return configurer;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Interceptor is required
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistration.<init>(InterceptorRegistration.java:49)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry.addInterceptor(InterceptorRegistry.java:45)
    com.example.package.configuration.ApplicationConfiguration.addInterceptors(ApplicationConfiguration.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addInterceptors(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:226)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a18d4f1.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$15(<generated>)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a18d4f1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c1cb4193.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a18d4f1.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Per Jukka's request:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: This shit is off-the-chain
    com.biblioboard.journal.configuration.ApplicationConfiguration.addInterceptors(ApplicationConfiguration.java:62)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addInterceptors(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:226)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53b9af71.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$27(<generated>)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53b9af71$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5c73fc1c.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53b9af71.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Does the `HandlerStageInterceptor` is on the scanned package `com.example.package` (inside it)

Comment: Yes, the interceptor is in the same package as the configuration file.  In this case, the scanned package is the base of the project so everything is scanned. As stated, this *does* work if I remove the Jasypt-related beans.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, remove the three @Bean annotated methods and then deliberately throw a runtime exception from the addInterceptors(..) method. Do you then see any CGLIB enhanced classes in the resulting stacktrace?

Comment: @Jukka Yeah, there are a 4 instances of a CGLIB class in the stacktrace. I've appended it to the question.

Comment: Ok. Not really sure what the issue is, but I'm fairly sure you can resolve the situation by just making the HandlerStageInterceptor another @Bean in your Configuration class and not use scanning/autowiring for it.

Comment: @Jukka Creating another `@Bean` method in the configuration class did resolve the issue, but I'm still wondering why. I'm gonna do some digging to see if I can figure out the why, but if you happen to find anything out please let me know. The curiosity is killing me.

Comment: Make the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer returning @Bean method static as per http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Comment: @Jukka I actually got around this by using the `@Import` and defining another configuration class to handle this. I cannot find anything yet that explicitly states their execution would come first, but it appears so from testing it.

Comment: @Jukka If you want to put together an answer for this, please do. If not please let me know and I will work on a comprehensive answer when I get the time.

Comment: Feel free to post the answer yourself. Mine was just a link to Google search results, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, simply resolved it by using `PropertiesFactoryBean` instead. I'm also wondering why `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` prevent autowiring.